# Angular material sort header not working after changed dataSource

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I can't figure out why row filtering doesn't work after changing data source on button click. The logic is built in such a way that after clicking the button, we receive a response from the api and set the dataSource to this response. But nothing works.

This my table template code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource1" matSort class="table table-bordered" [ngClass]="issetPerformer || !wasSearchingPerformer ? 'table-hover' : null" *ngIf="issetPerformer || !wasSearchingPerformer" #matTable>

                                                                <ng-container matColumnDef="dateF" class="table-head">
                                                                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (click)="consoleLog($event)">Дата</th>
                                                                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date }} </td>
                                                                </ng-container>

                                                                <ng-container matColumnDef="costF" class="table-head">
                                                                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Сума</th>
                                                                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"> {{paymentsPerformer[i].cost}} </td>
                                                                </ng-container>

                                                                <ng-container matColumnDef="detailsF" class="table-head">
                                                                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Примітки</th>
                                                                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.details}} </td>
                                                                </ng-container>

                                                                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnss"></tr>
                                                                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnss;"></tr>
                                                            </table>
```

At the beginning of the class, I created the required variables:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
paymentsPerformer: paymentsPerformer[] = [];
dataSource1  = new MatTableDataSource(this.paymentsPerformer);
displayedColumnss: string[] = ['dateF', 'costF', 'detailsF'];
```

This is type paymentsPerformer:

```
interface paymentsPerformer {
  date: string;
  cost: number;
  details: string;
}
```

So, after click on button is starting function where i getting json from api and setting this to paymentsPerformer variable:

```
showPaymentsPerformer() {
    this.api.showPerformerPaymentAdd(this.response.order.orderId + '_1').subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.wasSearchingPerformer = true;
      this.responsiveBodyPerformer = data.length >= 5;
      this.paymentsPerformer = data.map(i => {
        return {details: i.performerPaymentAddComment || ' ', cost: Number(i.performerPaymentAddSum), date: i.performerPaymentAddDate}
      });
      this.issetPerformer = true;
      this.wasSearchingPerformer = true;

    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.wasSearchingPerformer = true;
      this.paymentsPerformer = [];
      this.issetPerformer = false;
    }, () => {
      console.log('array', this.paymentsPerformer)
      this.dataSource1  = new MatTableDataSource(this.paymentsPerformer);
      this.dataSource1.sort = this.sort;
      console.log('this.dataSource1', this.dataSource1);
    });
  }
```

What happens at the beginning of the function doesn't matter, at the end of the function (on completion) I setting all data and try to sort again. But does not working.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: can you share a demo link

Comment: @Bilal Naqvi no sorry, if you need more info i can append to this post what you need?